# Azure Websites automated and manual backups are not created

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Whilst accepting that `Backups` in `Windows Azure Websites` are a preview feature, I can't seem to get them working at all. My site is approximately 3GB and on the standard tier. The settings are configured to move to a Geo-Redundant storage account with no other containers. There is no database selected, I'm only backing up the files.

In the `Admin Portal`, if I use the manual `Backup Now` button, a 0 bytes file is created within the designated storage account, dated `01/01/0001 00:00:00`. However even after several days, it is not replaced with the 'actual' file.

If I use the automated backup scheduler, nothing happens at all - no errors, no 0 byte files.

Can anyone shed any light on this please?

Comment: Can you provide some details from you're operation logs? Operation logs are found in the management tab in the full featured portal. Please be sure to remove any sensitive data before posting the operation logs to SO.

Comment: I tried it just now on a website.  It immediately produced a backup file of a few mb in my storage account.  I would suggest deleting the backup container from your storage account, turn off then back on the backup feature on your website.

Comment: @SyntaxC4
I just tried the manual Backup Now again. This time I saw the following in the operation logs:

    `Description:
    WebSite XYZ has an operation Backup and the status is Failed

    ErrorMessage:
    Conflict
    Detail: Backup is currently in progress. You cannot schedule     another one right now.
    ExtendedCode: 04212


    HttpStatusCode:
    409

    RequestId:
    a037ff15-4961-9e64-877b-9adfcfe8e140`
 

Which is odd as the scheduler for the backup was not due to run for another four days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backup/restore feature is still in a preview mode and officially supports only 2 GB of data. From the error message you posted ("backup is currenly in progress") it seems you probably hit a bug which was there and was fixed last week (the result of that bug was that there were some lingering backups which blocked subsequent backups).

Please try it again, you should be able to invoke it now. If you find another error message in operational logs, feel free to post it here (just leave the RequestId in it unscrambled - we can correlate using that) and we can take a look.

However, as I mentioned in the beginning, more than 2 GBs are not fully supported yet (you might not be able to do e.g. roundtrip with your data - backup and then restore).

Thanks,
Petr

Comment: Thanks. I had scheduled backup due 13/05/2014 03:00. This time the scheduler created a 0 bytes file but didn't complete (can see 'Backup operation started' in Ops logs) but no finish message. I just tried to re-run backup manually, got the same error: 
`WebSite XZY has an operation Backup and the status is Failed
ErrorMessage: Conflict
Detail: Backup is currently in progress. You cannot schedule another one right now.
ExtendedCode: 04212
HttpStatusCode:409
RequestId:1a6706e8-d94d-9427-a7b2-c918c4f9afb6`

Do you know if bug you mentioned is fixed on production or is this the 2GB limit?

Comment: @Petr Podhorsky I seem to be getting a similar error. My website is about 1.4GB and I'm trying to back it up. When I back it up I get, "Backup is currently in progress. You cannot schedule another one right now." Unfortunately it also looks like my operation logs aren't logging properly. Any suggestions on what to do? I've already turned off my automatic backup and turned it back on.

Comment: Edit: the logs work, I have to press a check box on the right that is white on a white background.. Unfortunately, I don't get much more detail other than there is a backup in progress.